# Using Windows forms c# message box

Tags: c#, winforms

How will I get a messagebox "Or another way of doing this" to have multiple lines?
I've got a messageBox to appear when the user presses F1 and I need it to have a sort of list:

```
Product Name = Alphanumeric + Special Characters.
Quantity = Maximum 100.
Price = Must be Numeric.
```

Etc
Thanks.

Comment: [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: MessageBox.Show("line one\nline two\nline three");

Comment: Also [Adding line break in C# Code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783310/adding-line-break-in-c-sharp-code-behind-page)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty that is not at all what the OP is asking. You're giving a link to a question to put line breaks in the editor for long strings, not in a messagebox that is to be shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\r\n` or `Environment.NewLine` at the end of each line to be shown or you can use the `StringBuilder` class:

```cs
    var message = new StringBuilder();
    message.AppendLine("Product Name = Alphanumeric + Special Characters.");
    message.AppendLine("Quantity = Maximum 100.");
    message.AppendLine("Price = Must be Numeric.");
    MessageBox.Show(message.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using \r\n but when you've got 9 lines of text it's quite bulky in the code, I've gone with StringBuilder ^^ Completely forgot about this code xD

Answer (score 3):

Add/concatenate `Environment.Newline` to your string.

Answer (score 2):

Put "\r\n" at the end of each line of the message.

so, for example:

```
        var message = "Product Name = MyProduct.\r\n";
        message += "Quantity = Maximum 100.\r\n";
        message += "Price = Must be Numeric.\r\n";

        MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Environment.NewLine` where you want a newline to appear. For example:

```
string message = "Line 1" + Environment.NewLine + "Line 2";
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

This will output:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```